# After deleting the aligned time series in certain device, why did Apache IoTDB still reported "timeseries under this device are aligned" error?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

In Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.1, this error is reported: `WARN  o.a.i.d.m.p.s.FragmentInstanceDispatcherImpl:357 - write locally failed. Message: org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.metadata.AlignedTimeseriesException: timeseries under this device are aligned, please use aligned interface` . When I wrote data, I tried to use non-aligned method first, and use aligned method next, but both failed and reported this error. I know that this message means this device is aligned for writing data, but I have already deleted the aligned time series, and I still get this error when writing again. Does anyone know what other reason this error may appear?